# Identification of a larva

Tags: entomology, species-identification

Last week-end I was working in my parent's garden and when I dig a bit the ground, I found few larvas I never seen before. My father told me there are there every time when he's doing the garden springtime.

I took some pictures (I just put it on leaves for the picture to see better than on the ground).

One low-res: 
[image: Larva-Unknown]

And the gallery [hi-resolution pictures](https://flic.kr/s/aHska4Tgts)

The location is in northern of Switzerland (Jura) at around 700 meters above the sea and the larvas were inside the ground in around 3-5 centimeters (1-2 inches) deep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is a cocoon for a [moth pupa](http://www.waldeneffect.org/blog/Moth_pupa_in_the_soil/).

[image: http://www.waldeneffect.org/blog/Moth_pupa_in_the_soil/]

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arAUDaQhW5E) is a link to a YouTube video of one hatching that is normal found in the soil.

Comment: Interesting, do you know how it look after?

Comment: @ruffp watch video link

Comment: Ok mine are a bit smaller (1-2 cm) but the video is impressive. But I don't know if there are still alive because it's not moving at all.